# Core Animation stops animation on app re-appearance

Tags: ios, objective-c, cabasicanimation

I have created animation to my menu using **CABasicAnimation**. Here below is my code relevant to this issue:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
  ...
  [self setAwesomeMenu];
}

- (void)setAwesomeMenu {
  ...
  //set tag for awesomemenu subview
  [menu setTag:awesomeMenuSubViewTag];

  [self addPulseFilterSubView];
}

- (void) addPulseFilterSubView {
// add pulseEffectFilter subview
  UIImageView *pulseEffectFilter = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pulse.png"]];
  [self.view insertSubview:pulseEffectFilter belowSubview:[self.view viewWithTag:awesomeMenuSubViewTag]];

  pulseEffectFilter.center = CGPointMake(160.0, 205.0);

  CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
  theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
  theAnimation.duration=2.0;
  theAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALL;
  //theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
  theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
  theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.3];
  [pulseEffectFilter.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform.scale"];
  theAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO; // doesn't help

  CABasicAnimation *fadeOutAnimation;
  fadeOutAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
  fadeOutAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.2];
  fadeOutAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
  fadeOutAnimation.duration = 1.0;
  fadeOutAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALL;
  [pulseEffectFilter.layer addAnimation:fadeOutAnimation forKey:@"opacity"];
  //fadeOutAnimation.autoreverses = YES;
  fadeOutAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO; //doesn't help

  [pulseEffectFilter setTag:pulseEffectFilterSubViewTag];
}
```

When I call this view first time the animation works just fine. When this app is re-appeared from phone suspension the animation also works fine. **But when I switch to another app or in the other word leave this app, then re-enter this app the animation is frozen.** I found one [article](http://richardwarrender.com/2011/09/core-animation-stops-ani-on-app-relaunch/) talking about this. They claimed it could be solved by setting a flag on the CABasicAnimation class called removedOnCompletion to NO. Unfortunately in my case it does not work. Does anyone know a solution to that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've tested your code and found a fix. In your app delegate add the following :

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"resumeAnimation" object:nil];
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}
```

Then add a bool to track if the animation is on and register the notification (in your view class) :

```
BOOL animationActive = NO;

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void) viewDidLoad {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addPulseFilterSubView) name:@"resumeAnimation" object:nil];

    [self setAwesomeMenu];
}
```

Then at the start of addPulseFilterSubView check if we need to stop the previous animation :

```
- (void) addPulseFilterSubView {

    if (animationActive) {
        for (UIView * view in self.view.subviews) {
            if (view.tag ==pulseEffectFilterSubViewTag) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }
    // add pulseEffectFilter subview
    UIImageView *pulseEffectFilter = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pulse.png"]];
    [self.view insertSubview:pulseEffectFilter belowSubview:[self.view viewWithTag:awesomeMenuSubViewTag]];
...
```

Then at the very end of this method :

```
    animationActive = YES;
}
```

And all should be good :D

Comment: First off thanks for your answer. It works fine now. However I just happened to see an issue only once I brought iOS notification center or quick menu by swiping from top down or bottom up. After those and getting back to the app, the animation animates regardless what condition is previously. For the condition that the animation should not animate, it animates. Do you know how to prevent that to happen?

Comment: Please do not mind me. I have solved the said issue from my earlier comment.